# How do you specify a threads dependency in cmake for distributing a header-only library in a cross-platform way?

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-platform

I was contributing to a nice little c++ header-only library and I was fixing up the cmake to make the library properly installable and findable/usable by other projects. The library itself does make use of various parts of the stl including those that you are required to link manually. Specifically it makes use of `std::thread` et al. How does one, in a cross-platform way, specify that a header-only library depends on linking `pthread` on linux but do something else on windows or other platforms?

Maybe this is a non-issue but I had assumed that you should do something like this for linux:

```
target_link_options(header-only-project INTERFACE -pthread)
```

However that would feel out of place on windows (where I guess you get threads without extra linker flags?). What's the right way to go about specifying dependencies like this in a cross platform way when distributing a library that isn't already in binary form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake comes with the `Threads` package for that very purpose:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(header-only-project INTERFACE Threads::Threads)
```

Comment: Ah yes I am aware of that but the main thing I'm worried about is that downstream projects know that my header only library depends on `Threads::Threads`. I had assumed that `Threads::Threads` is a target that resolves differently depending on the platform where you run `find_package(Threads)`. I don't understand how to generically say hey, when you use my header only library you will need to depend on `Threads::Threads`, whatever that works out to on your system. Maybe that is exactly how it works, I had just assumed that the Threads target was platform specific.

Comment: Ah but maybe indeed its a non-issue because doing `add_subdirectory` of the above cmake will indeed run `find_package` and resolve the `Threads` target only then on the target platform. Hahaha sorry for taking so long for it to sink in.. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Also what about `package_config_file`s? Will they work properly, passing along the thread dependency? I suppose they would too because you would have had to `make install` them on the target platform, presumably.

Comment: "when you use my header only library you will need to depend on Threads::Threads". That's what `target_link_libraries()` does. Any target depending on your library will "inherit" the dependency.

Comment: "Also what about package_config_file" as long as you `EXPORT` the target themselves and not just the headers and binaries, it should "just work".